# PF: One battery block, one IR receiver, two motors on same port

Tags: trains, power-functions

I have a heavy train with Power Functions. Now I want to use two train motors on the single loco. But as I understand, this is not possible with original LEGO parts? Do I need something like a three-way cable to connect two motors to the red pin of the IR receiver? If I connect one motor to red pin and second motor to blue pin — I will not be able to control both motors from one RC simultaneously, right?

**UPDATE:** Hey, I can stack connectors? Didn't notice that before.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE. Could you elaborate what do you mean by saying "PF 1.0" and "PF 2.0" here?

Comment: I corrected terms.

Comment: As well as stacking the connectors if you want to control two things at the same time you can build on the remote so that both switches or dials are moved in sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach (stack) more than one motor on the same connector (red or blue) of PF IR Receiver to control them at the same time. This is exactly what is being done in 9398 set, for example (although it uses V2 of PF IR Receiver). They will be spinning in the same direction with a push of a single button. If you need to reverse the rotation of one of the motors [Pole Reverser](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0339c01#T=C) comes to the rescue.

[image]

At this point of time there is no option with Powered Up to control both ports on the same receiver with a single button. Each port accepts just one motor, so you cannot make both motors attached to same receiver spin at the click of a single button - you need another receiver (on the same channel as the first one) for second motor to be controlled simultaneously.

**Edit**. Stacking motors on the same PF port/connector doesn't provide unlimited power and has its limit. Usually, couple of motors doesn't cause overheating protection to kick in, unless they are strained.

Comment: Ahhh! Just before your answer I noticed I can stack connectors. This must be the correct answer. I removed the part of my question about PU because I googled it and saw it is non-compatible.